# how can i add function to sum of value in react js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

here i m trying to add function in which monthly, basic and hra value already substracted by some formula

but in netSalary i want to sum of all value when i fill all input

```
    const onChange = (e) => {
    const annual = e.target.value;
    const monthly = Math.round((annual / 12)); // Math.round(annual / 12);
    const basic = Math.round((monthly / 100) * 50); // 50% of monthly
    const hra = Math.round((basic / 100) * 50); // 50% of basic

  //but below code is not doing same thing like sum 

    const fixedAllowance = e.target.value; // 10% of basic
    const variableAllowance = e.target.value; // 10% of basic
    const employerShare = e.target.value; // 10% of basic
    const statutoryBonus = e.target.value; // 10% of basic
    const netSalary = Math.round((basic + hra + payroll.employerShare + payroll.fixedAllowance + payroll.variableAllowance + payroll.statutoryBonus));
    setPayroll({
        ...payroll,
        annual,
        monthly,
        basic,
        hra,
        netSalary
    })

}
```

here is input field
and i want to auto focus on field when component load

here is my return code in which i m trying to post my data through fetch api and trying to get all sum value automatically

```
     return (
    <div className='payroll_main_container'>
        <form onSubmit={addPayroll}>
            <div className='form_group'>
                <label>Annual Salary</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='annual'
                    onChange={onChange}
                    ref={ref}
                    onFocus={() => {
                        ref.current.select();
                    }}
                    placeholder='Annual' />
                <label>Monthly Salary</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='monthly'
                    defaultValue={payroll.monthly}
                    placeholder='Monthly' />
                <label>Basic Salary</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='basic'
                    defaultValue={payroll.basic}
                    placeholder='Basic' />
                <label>HRA</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='hra'
                    defaultValue={payroll.hra}
                    placeholder='HRA' />
                <label>Fixed Allowance</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='fixedAllowance'
                    onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll, fixedAllowance: e.target.value })}
                    defaultValue={payroll.fixedAllowance}
                    placeholder='Fixed Allowance' />
                <label>Variable Allowance</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='variableAllowance'
                    onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll, variableAllowance: e.target.value })}
                    defaultValue={payroll.variableAllowance}
                    placeholder='Variable Allowance' />
                <label>Employer Share</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='employerShare'
                    onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll, employerShare: e.target.value })}
                    defaultValue={payroll.employerShare}
                    placeholder='Employer Share' />
                <label>Statutory Bonus</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='statutoryBonus'
                    onChange={(e) => setPayroll({ ...payroll, statutoryBonus: e.target.value })}
                    defaultValue={payroll.statutoryBonus}
                    placeholder='Statutory Bonus' />
                <label>Net Salary</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='netSalary'
                    defaultValue={payroll.netSalary}
                    placeholder='Net Salary' />

                <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => setPayroll(payroll)}>Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must show what result you get for `netSalary` and other values.
I think The result of `e.target.value` is `string` and you should consider using `Number(value)` for that.

Comment: yes, its string values. But when i considered the value Number(value) or parseInt(value), then having error or Nan.

Comment: so one of your ```string``` values is not convertible to ```number```. ```console.log()``` every parameter to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ali, You must check type for each e.target.value.

use below function:

```
const checkIsNumber = (x) => {
   if (isNaN(x)) {
     return 0;
   }
 return Number(x);
}
```

Usage:

```
checkIsNumber(e.target.value);
```